# GWT DataGrid setLoadingIndicator has no effect

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I'm trying to use the feature of GWT DataGrid to show an animated gif when data is loading from a RPC call to the server.

I didn't find any resource whatsoever anywehere. The support for this is really poor.

I inizialize my DataGrid using:

```
myDataGrid.setLoadingIndicator(new Image(/*my ImageResource object*/);
```

and during the flow of the program I use:

```
myDataGrid.fireEvent(new LoadingStateChangeEvent(LoadingState.LOADING));
```

when I want to put the DataGrid in the 'LOADING' state, i.e. just before making an RPC call, and then:

```
myDataGrid.fireEvent(new LoadingStateChangeEvent(LoadingState.LOADED));
```

just after the grid has been populated with data.

This doesn't work. I do not see any change in the DataGrid, I can't see the animated gif, it just remains unchanged during the process. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Please help.

Comment: Yes, I meant RPC (Remote Procedure Call). Yes the standard way GWT uses to communicate with the server. Do not focus on that. The question is about the loading state of the DataGrid. How can I set the 'Loading' state of the DataGrid so that it shows the loading indicator that I previously set using setLoadingIndicator() function, and after that, how then can I set back the normal, 'Loaded' state of the DataGrid so that is show the rows loaded? This is the real question. I used dataGrid.fireEvent(new LoadingStateChangeEvent(LOADING/LOADED)); but it seems to have no effect. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 9):

If you call `updateRowCount(0, false)`, the loading image will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks, for the response. Anyway I can't find the updateRowCount() method for DataGrid. What this method is referred to?

Comment: In fact I see that updateRow() is inherithed from AbstractDataProvider and is protected so I can't call it. Why is it protected? Is there another way?

Comment: It's protected because your data provider should call it.  So, when you ask your data provider for more information, your DP can IMMEDIATELY call `updateRowCount(0, false)`, and then, when your server call returns, call `updateRowCount(sizeOfResult, true)`

Comment: I understand, but my data provider is not a subclass of AsyncDataProvider<T> but it's just a simple ListDataProvider<T>. I don't define a MyDataProvider extends AsyncDataProvider<MyItem> {...} but I simply have a ListDataProvider<MyItem> so I don't have the possibility to call updateRowCount(). In fact, I really and simply need to put the datagrid in the state of 'Loading', is it really so complicated? I guess next release should simplify things a little.

Comment: you could try `dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<MyItem>() { public void updateRowCount(int rows, boolean b) { super.updateRowCount(rows, b);}}` I suppose, and call updateRowCount from outside of the provider. I think the GWT team intended the status of the display to be based entirely on the data provider, so I wouldn't necessarily expect an external command in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

I have several DataGrids in my application and I use the code-snippet below for all of them. You have to clear the data first, so that there are zero records in the grid, and then set the row-count to a number greater than zero.
Please note that the loading indicator is only animated while data is received via RPC. As soon as the grid is rendered (which may also take a while) the animation freezes.

```
    // Only required if you are using a pager
    int pageSize = pager.getPageSize();

    // This will trigger the onRangeChanged-event and call
    // the data provider
    dataGrid.setVisibleRangeAndClearData(new Range(0, 1), true);
    // Together with the row above, this will show the loading-indicator
    // in the data grid
    dataGrid.setRowCount(1);

    // Usually, the data is loaded when the data grid is initialized.
    // In my application, the user has to enter some input first and
    // then (re-)load the data via a button.
    // If you want your data grid to be filled when it is intialized,
    // simply remove the if-block
    if (dataProvider.getDataDisplays().size() == 0) {
        dataProvider.addDataDisplay(dataGrid);
    }

    // This will re-set the paging (only required if you are using a pager)
    dataGrid.setPageSize(pageSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in which version it was added, but in 2.8.0-beta1 I use `dataGrid.setRowCount(0, false)` to achieve something similar.